# Overriding UIStackView background color variable

Tags: swift, swift5, uistackview, ios14, uibackgroundcolor

I was shocked to learn that ability to set a background color to a UIStackView come only starting from iOS14. In the older versions such attempts are just ignored.
I have to support older versions as well, so I wrote this code to fix the issue:

```
public extension UIStackView {
    private var helperSubview: UIView {
        subviews.first(where: { $0.id == "helperSubview" }) ?? {
            let hsv = UIView()
            hsv.id = "helperSubview"
            insertSubview(hsv, at: 0)
            hsv.fillSuperview()
            return hsv
        }()
    }

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                return
            } else {
                helperSubview.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works just fine.
But there is one strange moment: in iOS14 `didSet` doesn't fire at all (like we can even don't check #availability). That suits me, this behaviour doesn't cause any problems. But I don't understand why does it behave like that?

Comment: May be because in iOS 14 it's already overriden

Comment: Is it a problem to change background color of stackView's superview?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Well, it's natural that there are many ways to fix a problem. But in order to change the stackView's superview color (and in some cases I have to create such a view first) I should refactor all my project, every stackView in my project. But my solution is fixing the problem throughout all the project automatically, I don't have to change a singe line of code.

Comment: @Roman Still waiting your project where you make this work in ANY iOS, macOS, padOS, watchOS version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use extension to override a class property. You need to subclass `UIStackView` if you would like to override any property or method.

From the docs:

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality

Comment: Yea, I heard about that before. Pretty annoying I must say. Because it's not always convenient to subclass. Especially if you only want slightly change behaviour of one variable. Luckily this theocratical rule can be violated in practice  In practice you can override in such a way, it will work 

Comment: @Roman you can override it but it will never be called.

Comment: But you can easily check by yourself that it's not the case. It is called. I've just checked one more time. It really works.

Comment: @Roman I am pretty sure this is not possible. https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0n0r7yimhdyehk/StackView%20Override%20BG.zip?dl=1. Can you please create a minimum project and share the link? Or simply fix what is wrong with my attempt

Comment: Now subclassing which works https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrszz6ogdybc0j2/StackView%20Override%20BG%20subclassing.zip?dl=1

Comment: @Roman Again there is no way to override a class property with extensions and this will probably never change.

Comment: Sorry for delay, was busy at work. I looked at your example, thank you. But it's not called not because it's overriden. Actually that was my initial question of the topic: why the backgroundCollor isn't called when being overriden in new iOS versions (14, 15). At the same time as when we override any other variables or backgroundColor itself in older versions it is called without any problems. Shortly speaking: in your example you chosen a bad variable to demonstrate your point.

Comment: But you know what. If you think about it... what we do here it doesn't contradict the rule you quoted from the documentation. Actually we don't override existing functionality of the variable in the extension. We add new functionality: didSet behaviour 

Comment: Prove I am wrong posting any project overriding any property or method from any class that would work. It can be just “adding functionality” as you say with didSet. Again it will never be called on any iOS period. There is no other answer to your question.

Comment: Btw I have already posted the solution to your issue. All you need is to subclass UIStackView. Don’t fight against the framework and or the language.