# Category Or Extention -- Which one will have precedence

Tags: swift, objective-c, extension-methods, objective-c-category

I write `awakeFromXib` in `UILabel` category plus Swift `UILabel` extension.
Now I add one brand new `UILabel` on `ViewController` (no outlet created).

`awakeFromNib` is being called from the category and not from Swift extension.

Please guide which one will have precedence and in what circumstances.

[image]

Note: ViewController parent class is written in Swift.

Comment: You are not supposed to ever try to override functionality in a category or extension. Only use those to add new methods. What you are doing is undefined which is why it's not behaving as you might expect.

Comment: @HangarRash the issue there is that you can NOT override a class property and or method using extension. It will NEVER be called.

Comment: There is a similar post here where the OP even downvoted my answer but what OP needs is subclass. Extension doesn’t work at all. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70875658/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus But the OP did override a method in an extension. See the picture in the question. Obviously there is a huge difference between can and should in this  case. Even though you can, you must not.

Comment: Yes I didn’t mean it doesn’t compile but it will never be called. The answer to what OP needs is subclassing/inheritance

Comment: @AabanTariqMurtaza - consider just Swift code, no Objective-C. Imagine creating two different extensions in two different files for the same class and method. Which one gets called, if either, is again completely undefined. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all - neither Swift extensions nor Objective-C categories should be used to override non-inherited methods (methods already defined in the class being extended). Apple mentions it in both [Swift Developer Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)..:

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they can’t override existing functionality.

..And [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) documentations:

> **If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as** a method in the original class, or **a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined** as to which method implementation is used at runtime.

If you look for a written "contract", it's emphasised in the quoted text above: if a method is defined in an extensions of a `Swift` class which itself is a subclass of `NSObject` (and `UILabel` is indirect subclass of `NSObject`) it gets dispatched with messaging mechanism (just like a method defined in an Objective-C category). Thus both methods follow the same Objective-C rules, dispatched the same way, have the same name and the same set of arguments. According to the Apple's own documentation in regards to Objective-C categories it means that **the behavior is undefined**.

You can probably find empirically some general pattern, but it is not guaranteed to be consistent (can work differently between or even within the same application session) and is a subject to change in future releases.

**P.S.** It's also double-discouraged to "shadow" Cocoa/Cocoa touch framework classes methods since you may end with suppressing the class own implementation from being called and consequently breaking the dependent logic.